# rsync with append smaller to longer file part that existing on receiver

Tags: rsync

I have some process that creates text log files, and some backup server. 
I want to move text log files to backup server (with remove source file). And on next rsync start if there is log file with the same name - append/concatenate it with previously moved file.

`rsync -av --append --remove-source-files user@server1:/source/ user@server2:/destination/`

And everything works great except - if there is file with the same name on source and destination, and destination/receiver have longer file than on source server - it's skipped. How I may disable this --append's file length verification? I want simply append files with the same name with no restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

The `append` option doesn't work like that.

From the man page:

> This causes rsync to update a file by appending data onto the end of
>   the file, which presumes that the data that already exists on the
>   receiving side is identical with the start of the file on the sending
>   side.

So, if you "append" a 2KB file to a 1KB file, the end file with be 2KB, and the first 1KB of the larger file **will be discarded**. Conversely, if you "append" a file of equal or smaller size, then the whole file will end up getting discarded.

By passing the `--append` option you're basically promising rsync that you *know* the start of the file will never change.

But, if you delete the file then the start of the file *has changed*. Likewise, logrotate will make bad things happen.

Conclusion: `--append` does not play nice with `--remove-source-files`.

The `--append-verify` option will solve the logrotate problem, but won't solve your problem because it will still discard data (albeit *different* data).